# Are parameters cached for executor.scheduleAtFixedRate()?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a line that runs a task repeatedly on a schedule:

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> Task.scanTask(task), 0, scanEvery, unit);
```

My question is, does that "task" parameter from the local variable get passed on every execution? or is it cached by the executor, so that changes to the local variable never make it to scanTask on next scheduled execution?

And is it bad practice to depend on each threads access to the current local value (not thread safe)?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without seeing how `task` is created, but if another thread has a copy of the reference whose value is in `task` in your code, and that other thread modifies the object that the reference refers to, the object being used by the executor will be modified.

Comment: But whether executor thread will see those changes or not depends on proper synchronization of `task` properties.

Comment: Oh very good point! The task being passed, has an ArrayList of objects to be processed (in order). There is no problem with other scan processes hitting the same objects at the same time as they are immutable. The only requirement I have is that the task needs to be swapped out without interrupting the scheduledExecution cadence. So if what is read is correct, the scanTask would receive the new task reference when the local variable has been changed (and if it misses the change due to race condition, it will pick it up on the next scheduled execution... Do I have that right?

Comment: @MicHD **(and if it misses the change due to race condition, it will pick it up on the next scheduled execution**. Not true, Java Memory model doesn't guarantee anything here if there is no synchronization. Depending on your particular JVM implementation it may or may not see the change. 
**the scanTask would receive the new task reference when the local variable has been changed** The reference will still be the same, but the contents of the object is changed.

Comment: @Ivan Thank you. That's a good point... Task needs to be volatile... and maybe even encapsulate it in another class (which is volatile) so that changing the task (not just the contents of its ArrayList member) will make its way to the next thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is using Lambda expression, the variable `task` will have to be effectively a constant.  I.e. it does not have to be a final variable, but its value should only be set once before the lambda, and then should never change.  And that same `task` object will be processed again and again in the threads.

Now, if the `task` object itself is a list or has a list inside, and if that keeps changing, then when the thread is triggered, whatever values are there in the list, those will be processed.